# Construction of a cut-off function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, continuity, special-functions

So basically the cut-off function that I am looking for has to satisfy the following properties:
$ \phi : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$

$ \phi \in C^2 $

$ \phi = 1 $ when $ |x| \leq r $

$ \phi = 0$ when x =2r and x= -2r

$ \phi = 1 $ when x = r and x = -r

and zero when $|x| > 2r$.

Basically to look like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nZd4.png)

Is there such function? The function that I found is

$ 1 ,$$ |x| \leq r$

0, $|x| \geq 2r$

$exp(\frac{-r^2}{r^2 - ( |x| -r )^2})e$,  $ r < |x| < 2r $

But its second derivative is not continuous.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: To make your question precise, you should use a more appropriate notation. For example, you are looking for a function $\phi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that has the following properties... $\phi(x)=1$ for all $x\in [-r,r]$.

Answer (score 1):

You may change that to $\exp\left(\dfrac{1}{9r^{4}}-\dfrac{1}{9r^{4}-(|x|^{2}-r^{2})^{2}}\right)$ for $r<|x|<2r$.

Comment: Thank for your help, but I tried to plot the graph of it https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3p1fwek5f6 and it doesnt satisfy the fact that $\phi = 0$ elsewhere.

Comment: You need to specify that $\phi=0$ on $\{|x|\geq 2r\}$ in the graphing software.

Comment: @KonstantinosFotiou, I have missed to change the indices, now it works, you may try to draw the new graph.